# Creating New columns by comparing existing columns(Copy Issue)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have some issue in my code.

I tried to create new columns by comparing existing two columns

Here is my example Dataframe

**occ_2019_pe:**

```
index            occ10        occ10_t1     
0                 20           20   
1                 20           12   
2                 30           30       
3                 40           34
```

I want to generate new column by using this code

```
occ_2019_pe['occ_change'] = np.where(occ_2019_pe['occ10']==occ_2019_pe['occ10_t1'], 0, 1)
```

However, it generate this issue,

```
<ipython-input-25-f48cdb1733d5>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  occ_2019_pe['occ_change'] = np.where(occ_2019_pe['occ10']==occ_2019_pe['occ10_t1'], 0, 1)
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: Where is 'occ10_t1' column?

Comment: Im sorry, I fixed it

Comment: it is only warning but code still can work. And if you don't see it then maybe use suggested `.loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run code with your small example then I don't get this error.

But maybe you should use suggested `.loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value`

```
occ_2019_pe.loc[:,'occ_change'] = np.where(occ_2019_pe['occ10']==occ_2019_pe['occ10_t1'], 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use assign.

```
occ_2019_pe = occ_2019_pe.assign(occ_change=np.where(occ_2019_pe['occ10']==occ_2019_pe['occ10_t1'], 0, 1))
```